# Join all points of a plot - R

Tags: r

I have to join some dots of a plot using R. 
For example this is my plot:
[image]

Now I am able just to join the first two points using this:

```
lines(x = c(x1, x2))
```

where `x1` and `x2` are the coordinates of these points.

How can I create a line that joins all points of the graph?

---EDIT
I have to join the points sequentially, so for example from `x2` I have to draw a line to `x3`, from `x3` to `x4` and so on.

For example, suppose I have this matrix:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide reproducible code. Also, do you need to join every point to every other one, or, sequentially on the x axis?

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question.

Comment: `lines(x_vector, y_vector)` ?